# My loop of random posts drags in comments of said random post

Tags: loop, reset

Hi I am setting up a random post generator so that a list of random posts from a chosen category can be displayed on a post. I also made it into a shortcode so it could be applied in an editor. THE ISSUE is that, it is displaying comments from the random posts generated. And I can't figure out why.

I do think it is something to do with the while loop I am using for this function, and it is for some reason interacting with the loop in the single.php and 'comments_template()' function, but I am not sure how to stop it

here is my code:

```
function aa_related_posts($id){

$args = array(
    'cat' => $id,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '4'
);

$rand_query = new WP_Query($args);

echo '<ul class="aa_rp">';

while($rand_query->have_posts()) : $rand_query->the_post(); 
    echo '<li> <b><a href="' , the_permalink() , '" target="_blank" >' , substr(get_the_title(), 0, 22) , '..</a></b></li>';    

endwhile; 

echo '</ul>';

}
```

and below is the code I use to make it into a shortcode:

```
function related_ad($atts, $content = null){
      extract(shortcode_atts(array('category' => 25), $atts));
      return aa_related_posts($category);
}
add_shortcode('related_ad', 'related_ad');
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think I fixed this... I used: "wp_reset_postdata();" after the while loop and it seemed to have everything fixxed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end of the loop and it stopped pulling in comments from the loops

here is more about [wp_reset_postdata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)